# Trying to ask for a file input and save it in specific location

Tags: python, tkinter, save

So I'm trying to program a method that saves a picture selected by the user and adds the picture to the parent class 'activity'. Here is what I tried:

```
    # Creating object from filedialog
    picture = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='r', title='Select activity picture', defaultextension=".jpg")
    
    # Check if cancelled
    if picture is None:
        return
    else:
        folder_dir = 'main/data/activity_pics'
        pic_name = 'rocket_league' #change to desc_to_img_name() later
        path = os.path.join(folder_dir, f'{pic_name}')
        
        # Making the folder if it does not exist yet
        if not os.path.exists(folder_dir):
            os.makedirs(folder_dir)
            
        # Creating a location object
        f = open(path, "a")
        
        # Writing picture on location object
        f.write(picture)
        
        # Closing
        f.close()

        # Check if successful
        if os.path.exists(path):
            print(f'File saved as {pic_name} in directory {folder_dir}')
            self.picture_path = path
```

And later, i call the method using `rocketleague.add_picture()`, where I defined rocketleague as an `Activity` class.

I've tried several different solutions I found online but none seem to work. Currently, this script gives an error:

```
C:\Users\timda\PycharmProjects\group-31\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/timda/PycharmProjects/group-31/project/activities/random_activity_generator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/timda/PycharmProjects/group-31/project/activities/random_activity_generator.py", line 160, in <module>
    rocketleague.add_picture()
  File "C:/Users/timda/PycharmProjects/group-31/project/activities/random_activity_generator.py", line 46, in add_picture
    f.write(picture)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

So I'm guessing my open.write() is not meant for anything but strings. I'm uncertain if my current method works at all.

What would be the most convenient way to do this?

Comment: Always make sure to post the full error code

Comment: @CoolCloud I've edited the post, will from now on post the full error code.

Comment: @TimRoodthe issue definitely seems to be trying to write to a binary file as a text file. You just want to MOVE the image to a different location, right? If yes, I'm writing an answer.

Comment: are you expecting `picture` to be a filename? It's not.

Comment: @PSSolanki I would like to copy the picture and place the copy in a specific folder so that I can call its path later in another method and open it.

Comment: @BryanOakley no, I'm expecting `picture` to be an image object

Comment: @TimRood: it is neither of those things. It is an open file handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described, you are using a completely different approach to do a task.

I'll first explain what you are trying to do and why it doesn't work.

-> So after you have asked the user to select a file, and having created `folder_dir` and `path`, you want to move/copy the picture selected to location described by variable `path`.

The Issues,

- You might be right here based on your needs but I feel you should be using `filedialog.askopenfile()` instead of `filedialog.asksaveasfile()`, because you probably want them to select a file, not select a folder to move the file to - you already seem to have the destination `folder_dir`. but again this is up to your needs.
- the important one. In your code where one of the comments says: """Creating a location object""" amd you used `f = open(path, "a")`, you didn't create a location object there. `f` is just a `file` object which is opened in text append mode - as indicated by `"a"` in second arg in the `open()` function call. You can't write binary image files to a text file. That's why the error message says, that it expects a string to be written to text file, not a binary I/O Wrapper.

## solution

Simple enough, use actual methods to move a file to perform the task.

So once you have address of an image file (selected by user in `filedialog` - explained above) - note that as @Bryan pointed out, `picture` variable will always `file handler` of the file selected by the user. We can get the absolute address of selected file using attribute `.name` of the `file handler`.

```
>>> import tkinter.filedialog as fd
>>> a = fd.askopenfile()
# I selected a test.txt file

>>> a
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/BeingProfessional/projects/Py/test.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

# the type is neither a file, not an address.
>>> type(a)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> import os

# getting the absolute address with name attribute
>>> print(a.name)
C:/BeingProfessional/projects/Py/test.txt
# check aith os.path
>>> os.path.exists(a.name)
True
```

NOTE:
We can also use `filedialog.askopenfilename()` which returns just the address of the file selected so that you don't have to worry about file handler and its attributes.

And we already have the destination `folder_dir` and a new fileName to be given.
And that's all we need, a source and destination.
Here is what to do to copy the file

These three methods do the same job. Use any one of 'em as needed.

```
import os
import shutil

os.rename("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
os.replace("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

Note that you must include the file name (file.foo) in both the source and destination arguments. If it is changed, the file will be renamed as well as moved.

Note also that in the first two cases the directory in which the new file is being created must already exist. On Windows machines, a file with that name must not exist or an `exception` will be raised, but `os.replace()` will silently replace a file even in that occurrence.

## Your code modified

```
# Creating object from filedialog
picture = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r', title='Select activity picture', defaultextension=".jpg")

# Check if cancelled
if picture is None:
    return
else:
    folder_dir = 'main/data/activity_pics'
    pic_name = 'rocket_league' #change to desc_to_img_name() later
    path = os.path.join(folder_dir, f'{pic_name}')
    
    # Making the folder if it does not exist yet
    if not os.path.exists(folder_dir):
        os.makedirs(folder_dir)
        
   # the change here
   shutil.move(picture.name, path)  # using attribute to get abs address

    # Check if successful
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print(f'File saved as {pic_name} in directory {folder_dir}')
        self.picture_path = path
```

The indentation of this code block is not great as the original question formatting didn't have it indented that great.

Thanks Bryan for pointing the mistakes out :)

Comment: _” @Bryan pointed out, picture variable will always contain the address of the file ”_ - that is incorrect. It is not an “address”, it is an open file handle.

Comment: Your solution never uses `picture`

Comment: @BryanOakley Yep. My bad. Editing the answer to reflect the same :)

Comment: I never thought about it in the sense of 'moving' the file. Thanks for the help! I was definitely stuck there in thinking I had to create the image as an object of some sorts while the simpler method is definitely moving the picture.

Comment: If all you need is the file name, you should should `askopenfilename` rather than `askopenfile`.

Comment: This is the fn I was looking for. I had used it before. I couldn't recall it for some reason. Thanks.